# How do I send objects from 1 device to another on the same internet connection?

Tags: python, sockets

this is my code but I'm pretty sure it only works locally (lmk if not)

server:

```py
#server
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 5034))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,adr=s.accept()
    clt.send(bytes("hello", "utf-8"))
```

client:

```
#client
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 5034))
msg=s.recv(1024)
print(msg.decode())
```

Comment: In client: `gethostname()` returns the local pc's name. You need to put the remote server's ip address there.

Comment: so that means the IP address of the server right?

Comment: oh never mind, it works when i put the IP of the server! Does this work when both devices are on different internet connections?

Comment: It works if the server PC is connected directly to the Internet. However, if the server is behind some kind of NAT you would need to set up [port forwarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=nat+port+forwarding) on the router and in the client use the WAN address and not the LAN address.

Comment: when i put in my WAN it gives me this error: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: This also assumes that the ISP is not blocking incoming connections. Some ISPs charge extra to let customers run servers on their network

Comment: @key_alt For different internet connections you need to set up port forwarding, or use IPv6, if your house has it. (It might not. IPv6 is like global warming, nobody is doing anything about it)